# CanActivate guard redirects to / on initial load, router-outlet does not render

Tags: angular, routes, auth-guard

I have a SPA with AuthGuard. If use is not logged page redirect error page otherwise redirects specific routes. Now.

1. User is not logged in
2. Call `/dashboard` and `Authgurad` redirects `/error?returnUrl=/dashboard`
3. User Call `/login?key=112233`
4. Login page subscribe to `AuthService` and create user token and redirects `/dashboard`
5. before render `/dashboard` triggered AuthGuard and AuthGurad lets them cause of everything is fine
6. `/dashboard` rendered normally
7. User wants navigate `/claim/search page`
8. Router changes page URL but `router-outlet` does not render redirected component
9. If user refresh window Page of browser works normally otherwise SPA does not work

My problem in step 8,9

my route :

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'dashboard',
    pathMatch: 'full',
  },
  {
    path: 'dashboard',
    component: DashboardPageComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard]
  },
  {
    path: 'claim',
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    children: [{
      path: 'search',
      component: ClaimSearchPageComponent,
    },
    {
      path: 'detail/:id',
      component: ClaimDetailPageComponent,
    }]
  },
  {
    path: 'login',
    component: LoginPageComponent,
  },
  {
    path: 'error',
    component: ErrorPageComponent,
  },
  {
    path: '**',
    component: ErrorPageComponent,
  }
];
```

login page :

```
ngOnInit() {
    this._returnUrl = this._route.snapshot.queryParams['returnUrl'] || '/';
    this._encryptedKey = this._route.snapshot.queryParams['key'];
    this._authenticationService.login(this._encryptedKey)
      .subscribe(
        data => {
          this._router.navigate([this._returnUrl]);
        });
  }
```

Auth Service :

```
public get isLogged(): boolean {
    return !!this.currentUserSubject.value;
}
public login(encryptedKey: string) {
    return super.httpPostModel(User, environment.apiService.endPoints.user.login, { key: encryptedKey }).pipe(map(user => {
        sessionStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify(user));
        this.currentUserSubject.next(user);
        return user;
    }));
}
```

auth guard

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean {
    if (this._authenticationService.isLogged) {
        return true;
    }
    this._router.navigate(['/error'], { queryParams: { returnUrl: state.url } });
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For **component-less routes** (without router outlet) you can use  **canActivateChild** not **canActivate**, I suggest that you add a ClaimComponent with that content only

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

and change routes to

```
{
 path: 'claim',
 component: ClaimComponent, // add this
 canActivate: [AuthGuard],
 children: [{
   path: 'search',
   component: ClaimSearchPageComponent,
 },
 {
   path: 'detail/:id',
   component: ClaimDetailPageComponent,
 }]
},
```

in case of component-less routes, canActivateChild runs before any child route is activated:

```
{
 path: 'claim',
 canActivateChild: [AuthGuard],
 children: [{
   path: 'search',
   component: ClaimSearchPageComponent,
 },
 {
   path: 'detail/:id',
   component: ClaimDetailPageComponent,
 }]
},
```

Answer (score 0):

In your routes, You need to specify the component property for the parent component(claim component) also.

Try this :

```
{
    path: 'claim',
    component: ClaimPAgeComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    children: [{
      path: 'search',
      component: ClaimSearchPageComponent,
    },
    {
      path: 'detail/:id',
      component: ClaimDetailPageComponent,
    }]
  }
```